# Sending definitions from the subkernels to the kernel

Tags: parallelization, variable-definitions

Sometimes it is convenient to define an indexed quantity `g[i]` as in

```
 f[i_] := (Pause[5]; i^2);
 Do[g[i] = f[i], {i, 10}];
```

A straightforward parallelization of the above is to use

```
 f[i_] := (Pause[5]; i^2);
 ParallelDo[g[i] = f[i], {i, 10}];
```

The above defines each value of `g[i]` in a subkernel, none of them being accessible by the kernel.

Indeed, in a computer with 4 subkernels, I find

```
 g[1]
 (*g[1]*)

 ParallelEvaluate[DownValues[g]]
 (*{
    {HoldPattern[g[1]] :> 1, HoldPattern[g[2]] :> 4, HoldPattern[g[9]] :> 81},
    {HoldPattern[g[3]] :> 9, HoldPattern[g[4]] :> 16, HoldPattern[g[10]] :> 100},
    {HoldPattern[g[5]] :> 25, HoldPattern[g[7]] :> 49}, 
    {HoldPattern[g[6]] :> 36, HoldPattern[g[8]] :> 64}
 }*)
```

One way to have all the `g[i]` values defined in the kernel is to use `ParallelTable` as follows:

```
 f[i_] := (Pause[5]; i^2);
 vectorG = ParallelTable[f[i], {i, 10}];
 g[i_] := g[i] = vectorG[[i]];
```

The approach above works, but it is less flexible. Suppose that after computing everything up to i = 10 one realises that it is better to compute from `i= 11` to `15` as well. In the first approach one would simply add the line `ParallelDo[g[i] = f[i], {i, 11, 15}]`). Another drawback of the last solution: when parallel computations are not used, one could identify `f` with `g`, such that `g[1]` is computed only if it was not executed before. The approach above with `vectorG` does not allow for this extension neatly.

It seems reasonable to me to try to use the first approach, with `g[i]` defined in the subkernels. To use this route, one must send the `g[i]` definitions from the subkernels to the kernel. I found that the following works (without introducing parallelization issues, as `SetSharedFunction` does):

```
 f[i_] := (Pause[5]; i^2);
 ParallelDo[g[i] = f[i], {i, 10}];
 (ParallelEvaluate[DownValues[g]] // Flatten) /. {y_[g[x_]] -> g[x], RuleDelayed -> Set};

 g[2]
 (* 4 *)
```

Am I missing other natural ways to bring the `g[i]` definitions to the kernel?  Does the approach above seem robust, clear and efficient to be applied in general?